# How can I clear my Discord bot's status after it has been set?

Tags: discord.js

I have some code that gives my bot a status and I want it to clear with the use of a command. I am able to change the status, but I can't clear it.

Here's the code that I use to give the bot it's status:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
    targetGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('729676078599110776')

    client.user.setPresence({
        status: 'online',
        activity: {
            name: `${targetGuild.memberCount} members | !c help`,
            type: "WATCHING"
        }
    });
});
```

I've tried clearing it by setting the presence without adding the status itself, but that seems to just leave it the same.

```
client.user.setPresence({
    status: 'online'
});
```

Comment: I believe you can just do `client.user.setActivity()` or `client.user.setPresence({ activity: null })`. The ladder is probably better for readability purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `client.user.setPresence({ activity: null })` will clear the status, and if you want to log out of the bot so it's offline, you can do `client.destroy()`